# Cumulative sum over ROW in Dynamic Cross Table (QlikSense)

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

I have a measure "Sales" by "month":

| month | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 01-2023 | 10 |
| 02-2023 | 20 |
| 03-2023 | 15 |
| 04-2023 | 30 |
| 05-2023 | 13 |

and I need the cumulative sum presented in a Dynamic cross table :

| month | 01-2023 | 02-2023 | 03-2023 | 04-2023 | 05-2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | 10 | 30 | 45 | 75 | 88 |

I tried using

```
RangeSum(Above(TOTAL Sum(Sales), 0, RowNO(TOTAL)))
```

It works for normal tables (by column) but when I use it in a dynamic cross table (by row), I get:

| month | 01-2023 | 02-2023 | 03-2023 | 04-2023 | 05-2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I've also seen solutions involving changing the script but it would almost double the size of my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are transposing the `month` dimension then the values are becoming columns.

The expression should be changed to respect that:

- `Above` is now `Before`
- `RowNo` is now `ColumnNo`

The full expression will be:

`Rangesum(Before(Sum(Sales),0,ColumnNo()))`

And the result table is:

[image: Result table]